# JQuery returns NaN but not always

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass the score of a test to a php script which then emails the result to the user. I am outputting the score to the console which works great (shows me my percentage) but when the email is sent instead of the score it says NaN.

Here's my code...

```
 score = roundReloaded(trueCount / questionLength * 100, 2);

          $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: config.sendResultsURL,
                  data: { q:score },
                  complete: function () {console.log("Sending complete. The score was "+ score + "%");}
                });
```

And my emailData.php file...

```
$body = "You scored " . $_POST['q'] . "%";
$to = "someone@test.com";
$email = 'admin@test.com';

$subject = 'Results';
$headers  = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

// Send the email:
$sendMail = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Can someone help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log()` to check that 'trueCount' and 'questionLength' are both numbers?

Comment: Just tried isNaN(score) and it returned false. I just don't understand it!!!

Comment: What is your roundReloaded function doing?  is it returning a string or a number?  The calculations are completing correctly?

Comment: also try this `data: { q:+score },`

Comment: To echo wirey, I think your problem is either in your `roundReloaded()` function or wherever you're getting the 'trueCount' and 'questionLength' variables from. It may be helpful to show this code as well.

Comment: My roundReloaded function is...`function roundReloaded(num, dec) {
        var result = Math.round(num * Math.pow(10, dec)) / Math.pow(10, dec);
        return result;
    }`

Comment: Ok so thanks to wirey and splatio I have finaaly got it working. trueCount wasn't being declared until after the script ran. However, I still don't understand how the console was showing the correct score. How does the console do it?

Comment: the complete function of ajax runs whether ajax completes successfully or errors.  So it's the last to run

Answer (score 0):

NaN says it's not a number. Try converting $_POST['q'] to a number like :

```
$_POST['q']*1
```

Or maybe it's form side problem, try converting score variable to string :

```
score = roundReloaded(trueCount / questionLength * 100, 2);

          $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: config.sendResultsURL,
                  data: { q:score+'' },
                  complete: function () {console.log("Sending complete. The score was "+ score + "%");}
                });
```

EDIT : try this for better logging :

```
score = roundReloaded(trueCount / questionLength * 100, 2);
var params = {q:score};
console.log(JSON.stringify(params));    
          $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  url: config.sendResultsURL,
                  data: params,
                  complete: function () {console.log("Sending complete. The score was "+ params.q + "%");}
                });
```

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the form before the email is sent. In the console it says 'Sending complete. The score was 100%' but in the Post section it says Parameters: q NaN, Source: q=NaN. Any ideas?

Comment: if you try with data: "q="+score, instead? And you could add a console.log(JSON.parse({q:score})); just to make sure how it convert. also try putting this into a variable before

Answer (score 0):

if the first character of the string cannot be converted to a number. then returns NaN .

so here problem in convertion

Comment: Why would it be that the console can read 'score' but passing it using $_POST results in it saying NaN? Any ideas?